# How do I have a Readonly Field that will save

Tags: jquery, html

I have a readonly field that is populated by a popup window search widget. The problem I am having is that when I open an existing record, that field will not display since it is readonly. I then made it so that it is readonly only after the record is opened so it populates but now I need to be able to saved the readonly record and it is not doing that either. Does anyone know a good workaround for this?

Comment: `readonly` fields should save as long as they have a `name` attribute. Can you post your HTML and JS code?

Comment: Your question is too vague.  We can't help you if you don't post any code.

Comment: I don't need you to look at my code im asking if there are any work arounds for this type of issue. I did find a resolution, I set the value of the field, set it as readonly, then before the save ajax I removed the attribute. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did find a resolution, I set the value of the field, set it as readonly, then before the save ajax I removed the attribute. thanks